# How to obtain the statistic of the frequency of words in a buffer

Tags: text

For linguists and many other scientists, analyzing the frequency of the words appearing in a text is a great tool. Some commercial text editors and some websites provide this tool.

In word frequency analysis, sort the words in decreasing order with respect to their frequency. For example in this text:

`Emacs Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for those using, extending, or developing the emacs text editor. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about emacs.`

we have:

```
56 words
9: punctuation marks

3: ,
3: .
3: a
3: emacs
3: of
2: '
2: and
2: exchange
2: question
2: stack
2: the
2: to
1: &
1: about
1: answer
1: answers
1: as
1: build
1: built
1: by
1: detailed
1: developing
1: editor
1: every
1: extending
1: for
1: help
1: is
1: it
1: library
1: network
1: or
1: part
1: q
1: re
1: run
1: s
1: site
1: sites
1: text
1: those
1: together
1: using
1: we
1: with
1: working
1: you
1: your
```

I am wondering if there exists already a package which can be used to provide such statistics.

PS I have already asked different question in the same spirit and an [excellent answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/8071/)  was provided (I wish to upvote it more if I could).

Comment: Wouldn't going one step further and building an inverse index be preferable? (It is easy to asses a word frequency given inverse index, but you can use the index to find other interesting things, like whether two words appear close together in the document). I've been playing with Sphinx recently, so, maybe connecting it to Emacs would provide more search options?

Comment: @wvxvw yes, it would be a great idea. I have no experience with Sphinx, but if you know how to use it with emacs I would be glad to learn about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The format of output (org-mode table) is inspired by [the link](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/8071/3889) in your question.

```el
(require 'cl-lib)

(defvar punctuation-marks '(","
                            "."
                            "'"
                            "&"
                            "\"")
  "List of Punctuation Marks that you want to count.")

(defun count-raw-word-list (raw-word-list)
  (cl-loop with result = nil
           for elt in raw-word-list
           do (cl-incf (cdr (or (assoc elt result)
                             (first (push (cons elt 0) result)))))
           finally return (sort result
                                (lambda (a b) (string< (car a) (car b))))))

(defun word-stats ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((words (split-string
                 (downcase (buffer-string))
                 (format "[ %s\f\t\n\r\v]+"
                         (mapconcat #'identity punctuation-marks ""))
                 t))
         (punctuation-marks (cl-remove-if-not
                             (lambda (elt) (member elt punctuation-marks))
                             (split-string (buffer-string) "" t )))
         (raw-word-list (append punctuation-marks words))
         (word-list (count-raw-word-list raw-word-list)))
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*word-statistics*")
      (erase-buffer)
      (insert "| word | occurences |
               |-----------+------------|\n")

      (dolist (elt word-list)
        (insert (format "| '%s' | %d |\n" (car elt) (cdr elt))))

      (org-mode)
      (indent-region (point-min) (point-max))
      (goto-char 100)
      (org-cycle)
      (goto-char 79)
      (org-table-sort-lines nil ?N)))
  (pop-to-buffer "*word-statistics*"))
```

Comment: There are three forms not just `word-stats`, you need to eval all of them.

Comment: I have no clue why it doesn't work for you. As you can see, `punctuation-marks` already defined in the first form.

Comment: I confirm that it works now. I may happen that I had not copied the first paragraph.

Comment: In a minimalist emacs environment (v24.5), I had to add `(require 'cl)` to use the `incr` command.

Comment: @Chadwick I've updated the answer to use `cl-incf` instead of `incf` and require `cl-lib` explicitly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I'm getting `or: Symbol’s function definition is void: first`. My Emacs version is 28.2

Comment: changing `(first ...` to `(car ...` works now.

Answer (score 4):

Eval the following code and type M-x word-frequency in a buffer with the text. You will get a buffer with the number of word occurence and percent value.

```
(defvar word-frequency-table (make-hash-table :test 'equal :size 128))

(defvar word-frequency-buffer "*frequencies*"
  "Buffer where frequencies are displayed.")

(defun word-frequency-incr (word)
  (puthash word (1+ (gethash word word-frequency-table 0)) word-frequency-table))

(defun word-frequency-list (&optional reverse limit)
  "Returns a cons which car is sum of times any word was used
and cdr is a list of (word . count) pairs.  If REVERSE is nil
sorts it starting from the most used word; if it is 'no-sort
the list is not sorted; if it is non-nil and not 'no-sort sorts
it from the least used words.  If LIMIT is positive number
only words which were used more then LIMIT times will be
added.  If it is negative number only words which were used
less then -LIMIT times will be added."
  (let (l (sum 0))
    (maphash
     (cond
      ((or (not (numberp limit)) (= limit 0))
       (lambda (k v) (setq l (cons (cons k v) l) sum (+ sum v))))
      ((= limit -1) (lambda (k v) (setq sum (+ sum v))))
      ((< limit 0)
       (setq limit (- limit))
       (lambda (k v) (setq sum (+ sum v))
         (if (< v limit) (setq l (cons (cons k v) l)))))
      (t
       (lambda (k v) (setq sum (+ sum v))
         (if (> v limit) (setq l (cons (cons k v) l))))))
     word-frequency-table)
    (cons sum
          (cond
           ((equal reverse 'no-sort) l)
           (reverse (sort l (lambda (a b) (< (cdr a) (cdr b)))))
           (t       (sort l (lambda (a b) (> (cdr a) (cdr b)))))))))

(defun word-frequency-string (&optional reverse limit func)
  "Returns formatted string with word usage statistics.

If FUNC is nil each line contains number of times word was
called and the word; if it is t percentage usage is added in
the middle; if it is 'raw each line will contain number an
word separated by single line (with no formatting) otherwise
FUNC must be a function returning a string which will be called
for each entry with three arguments: number of times word was
called, percentage usage and the word.

See `word-frequency-list' for description of REVERSE and LIMIT
arguments."
  (let* ((list (word-frequency-list reverse)) (sum (car list)))
    (mapconcat
     (cond
      ((not func) (lambda (e) (format "%7d  %s\n" (cdr e) (car e))))
      ((equal func t)
       (lambda (e) (format "%7d  %6.2f%%  %03d %s\n"
                           (cdr e) 
               (/ (* 1e2 (cdr e)) sum) 
               (length (car e))
               (car e))))
      ((equal func 'raw) (lambda (e) (format "%d %s\n" (cdr e) (car e))))
      (t (lambda (e) (funcall func (cdr e) (/ (* 1e2 (cdr e)) sum) (car e)))))
     (cdr list) "")))

(defun word-frequency (&optional where reverse limit func)
  "Formats word usage statistics using
`word-frequency-string' function (see for description of
REVERSE, LIMIT and FUNC arguments) and:
- if WHERE is nil inserts it in th e
  or displays it in echo area if possible; else
- if WHERE is t inserts it in the current buffer; else
- if WHERE is an empty string inserts it into
  `word-frequency-buffer' buffer; else
- inserts it into buffer WHERE.

When called interactively behaves as if WHERE and LIMIT were nil,
FUNC was t and:
- with no prefix argument - REVERSE was nil;
- with universal or positive prefix arument - REVERSE was t;
- with negative prefix argument - REVERSE was 'no-sort."

  (interactive (list nil
                     (cond
                      ((not current-prefix-arg) nil)
                      ((> (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg) 0))
                      (t 'no-sort))
                     nil t))
  (clrhash word-frequency-table)
  (word-frequency-process-buffer)
  (cond
   ((not where)
    (display-message-or-buffer (word-frequency-string reverse limit func)
                               word-frequency-buffer))
   ((equal where t)
    (insert (word-frequency-string reverse limit func)))
   (t
    (display-buffer
     (if (and (stringp where) (string= where ""))
         word-frequency-buffer where)
     (word-frequency-string reverse limit func)))))

(defun word-frequency-process-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((buffer (current-buffer))
        bounds
        beg
        end
        word)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "\\<[[:word:]]+\\>" nil t)
;;    (while (forward-word 1)
        (word-frequency-incr (downcase (match-string 0)))
;;      (setq bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'word))
;;      (setq beg (car bounds))
;;      (setq end (cdr bounds))
;;      (setq word (downcase (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end)))
;;      (word-frequency-incr word)
        ))))
```

Comment: I conform that your code works well. Is it possible to modify it, in order that it count punctuation marks as well?