# How to get word statistics of RSS feeds via Elfeed?

Tags: elfeed

I'm using [Elfeed](https://github.com/skeeto/elfeed) as an RSS client. Given an `*elfeed-search*` buffer, I would like to know the word frequencies in the current search. I've looked at [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13518/19333), and while the proposed function works great for a normal buffer with text, it breaks in the above scenario.

Ideally, I would like count only the frequencies of the words that appears in the titles, not in the publishers' names, tags, or dates.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this? Alternatively, any pointers to relevant elisp tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the titles in the current *elfeed-search* buffer like this:

```
(with-current-buffer "*elfeed-search*"
  (cl-loop for entry in elfeed-search-entries
       collect
       (elfeed-entry-title entry)))
```

I assume you can take this list and process it using the linked solution or something like it?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I've replaced `collect` with `concat` and can feed it right into the linked solution. There are some cases where I get an error, but I'm sure I'll be able to find a solution on my own. Thanks again!

Comment: If the error isn't important, e.g. if it is from entries with no title, you can wrap the title command in (ignore-errors ...). or put some other test for stringp, or do something like concat (or (elfeed-entry-title entry) "").